# How old was Miguel O'Hara when he became Spider-Man 2099?

Tags: marvel, comics, age, marvel-2099, spider-man-2099

*[Spider-Man 2099](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_2099)* is about Miguel O'Hara who gets his DNA spliced with that of a spider and takes on the mantle of Spider-Man. How old was Miguel when this happened? He seems to be an established employee of Alchemax and has his own place, so I'm guessing he's in his mid 20s, but I have no idea what is common in the year 2099.